# Schedule Netty client

Tags: netty

I've to write a client/server application where the client has to send to the server some information each hour or each day (the schedule should be sets by user).

I searched for an integration Netty -> Quartz, but I didn't find nothing.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would there be a need for a specific integration between Quartz and Netty? Just create a Quartz job that, when triggered, calls your specific Netty client.

Comment: Thanks. In effect I don't want an integration, just a method to launch the client in a schedule base. I tried Qartz and seems to work. I only have a log4j problem because both uses it and I've warning starts the Netty server and the Qartz launcher: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (EchoQuartz).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Comment: I solved the log4j warning with the creation of log4j.properties file.